# Linking a PostMapping function in the Controller class to the Service class function

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, response-entity

I have this function addBug(String title, String description, LocalDateTime created, LocalDateTime updated, ObjectId projectId) in my Service class:

```
public Bug addBug(String title, String description, LocalDateTime created, LocalDateTime updated,
            ObjectId projectId) {
        Bug newBug = bugRepository.insert(new Bug(title, description, created, updated));

        mongoTemplate.update(Project.class)
                .matching(Criteria.where("_id").is(projectId))
                .apply(new Update().push("bugs").value(newBug))
                .first();

        return newBug;
        // return bugRepository.save(bug); // old way
    }
```

I want to use this in my Controller class, using a '@PostMapping' using the function 'createBug()', this is how i coded the function but I am getting an error,

```
@PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Bug> createBug(@RequestBody Bug bug) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Bug>(bugService.addBug(bug), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

How do I correctly make use of the 'addBug()' function  the 'createBug()' function?
I am new to spring and java.

I tried passing the same variables as in addBug() when using it in the createBug() but I still get error lines.

Comment: "I am getting an error" ... what error do you get? you must pass all the parameters the signature of your method takes, otherwise it won't find the method